# Unable to get GWT ListDataProvider to work with DataGrid

Tags: gwt, datagrid, dataprovider

I had my data in a FlexTable, but am migrating to a DataGrid so I can easily add pagination.  I get the data via a REST call.  I can't seem to get the data to actually display.  Here are the relevant snippets:

```
    private DataGrid<SearchResult> resultsGrid = new DataGrid<SearchResult>();
    resultsGrid.setAutoHeaderRefreshDisabled(true);

        TextColumn<SearchResult> titleColumn = new TextColumn<SearchResult>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(SearchResult object) {
                return object.getTitle();
            }
        };
        resultsGrid.addColumn(titleColumn, "Document Title");

        ButtonCell buttonCell = new ButtonCell();
        Column<SearchResult, String> buttonColumn = new Column<SearchResult, String>(buttonCell){
            @Override
            public String getValue(SearchResult object) {
                return "Show";
            }
        };

        resultsGrid.addColumn(buttonColumn, "");
        buttonColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<SearchResult, String>() {
            public void update(int index, SearchResult object, String value) {
                doPreview(object.title);
            }
        });

        TextColumn<SearchResult> roleColumn = new TextColumn<SearchResult>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(SearchResult object) {
                return object.getRoles();
            }
            @Override
            public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, SearchResult object) {
                if (object.containsCurrentRole)
                    return "highlight";
                else
                    return null;
            }
        };

        resultsGrid.addColumn(roleColumn, "Associated Roles");

        final SingleSelectionModel<SearchResult> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<SearchResult>();
        resultsGrid.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
        selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
            public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
              SearchResult selected = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
              if (selected != null) {
                  clearWordCloud();
                  getWordCloud(selected.getTitle());
              }
            }
          });

        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(resultsGrid);

        // Create a Pager to control the table.
        SimplePager.Resources pagerResources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
        pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pagerResources, false, 0, true);
        pager.setDisplay(resultsGrid);
        resultsGrid.setVisible(true);
        resultsGrid.addStyleName("results");
        mainPanel.add(resultsGrid);

...
```

The function that gets called  after a search:

```
 private void updateTable(List<SearchResult> results) {

          dataProvider.getList().addAll(results);
          dataProvider.refresh();
          dataProvider.flush();
          resultsGrid.setVisible(true);
          resultsFlexTable.setVisible(true);
      }
```

At first I was missing the flush and refresh, but adding them had no effect.  I'm kind of stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem is that your DataGrid has a height of zero. DataGrid implements RequiresResize, which means that its height either has to be set explicitly, or it will acquire its height from a parent widget if this parent widget implements ProvidesResize. FlexTable does not implement ProvidesResize interface.

NB: You don't need `flush` and `refresh` - adding data to the DataProvider refreshes the grid.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. It's disappointing that the documentation doesn't mention something so critical.